# Why my search against elasticsearch using NEST and C# is not returning any document?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, mapping, nest, bulkinsert

I'm new on elasticsearch world and I have a requirement to search for documents with a specific GUIDs. I've already figure out that to do that I need to map my GUID field as a keyword field.
There is a code already in production that is performing the indexing of the documents, but no mapping is being made. See below the actual code:

```
    public class ProjectFileES
    {
        public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    [...]

    var _bulkDescriptor = new BulkDescriptor();

    _bulkDescriptor.CreateMany<ProjectFileES>(list, (bd, q) =>
            bd.Id(q.Id.ToString())
                .Index($"{AppConstants.ES_IndexName}-{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}")
                .Type(AppConstants.ES_Type)
        );

        return await Client.BulkAsync(_bulkDescriptor);
```

As I read in the Elastic documentation, GUIDs are auto mapped to keyword type, as you can see below.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "projectfilees": {
      "properties": {
        "clientId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "projectId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "displayName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "fileName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
# Response:
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "index" : "roger-test3"
}
```

But now I'm trying to Search passing a projectId of a document which is indexed, as following:

```
var response = await _elastic.SearchAsync<ProjectFileES>(s => s.RequestConfiguration(c => c.DisableDirectStreaming())
                        .Index("*")
                        .Query(q =>
                            q.Bool(b => b
                                .Filter(f => f
                                    .Term(t => t.ProjectId, projectId)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

but my response object have no documents returned:
[Response Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izH7b.png)

Here is the JSON response inside the DebugInformation property:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "ProjectId": {
              "value": "45efa5d0-8b41-11ea-871b-e3b070662e35"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
# Response:
{
  "took" : 48,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 373,
    "successful" : 373,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: As far as I know if the field isn't created as keyword type when create the index and indexing the document, you cannot use it

Comment: Can you check the mapping ,By default a string is mapped as text and keyword (as subfield). If subfield keyword/raw not present you will have to re-create index

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your comments, but the thing is that there are still no mapping at all. Currently it is being indexed without any explicit mapping, and my question is exactly how I can perform a mapping using the _bulkDescriptor.CreateMany method. If it is not possible, what is the alternative for bulk indexing with mapping?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect my last progress, but still I'm not being able to retrieve any document from my search...